# What is 'MagicBooleans', 'MagicStrings' in alicebot package?

Tags: java, chat, bots, chatbot, aiml

I have found a code for simple chatbot using AIML and Program-ab distribution. There is a use of MagicBooleans and MagicStrings at many places. What exactly are those ? Also, I didn't understood what is a trace_mode ? 
The code that I found is as follows -

```
import java.io.File;
import org.alicebot.ab.Bot;
import org.alicebot.ab.Chat;
import org.alicebot.ab.History;
import org.alicebot.ab.MagicBooleans;
import org.alicebot.ab.MagicStrings;
import org.alicebot.ab.utils.IOUtils;

public class ChatBot {
private static final boolean TRACE_MODE = false;
static String botName = "super";

public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {

       String resourcesPath = "/home/user/eclipse-workspace/myProject/src/main/resources";
       System.out.println(resourcesPath);

        MagicBooleans.trace_mode = TRACE_MODE;
        Bot bot = new Bot("super", resourcesPath);
        Chat chatSession = new Chat(bot);
        bot.brain.nodeStats();
        String textLine = "";

        while(true) {
            System.out.print("Human : ");
            textLine = IOUtils.readInputTextLine();
            if ((textLine == null) || (textLine.length() < 1))
                textLine = MagicStrings.null_input;
            if (textLine.equals("q")) {
                System.exit(0);
            } else if (textLine.equals("wq")) {
                bot.writeQuit();
                System.exit(0);
            } else {
                String request = textLine;
                if (MagicBooleans.trace_mode)
                    System.out.println("STATE=" + request + ":THAT=" + ((History) chatSession.thatHistory.get(0)).get(0) + ":TOPIC=" + chatSession.predicates.get("topic"));
                String response = chatSession.multisentenceRespond(request);
                while (response.contains("&lt;"))
                    response = response.replace("&lt;", "<");
                while (response.contains("&gt;"))
                    response = response.replace("&gt;", ">");
                System.out.println("Robot : " + response);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Comment: From [the JavaDoc of the class](https://github.com/blueshen/program-ab/blob/master/src/org/alicebot/ab/MagicBooleans.java) "Global boolean values that control various actions in Program". StackOverflow should not be an alternative to simply googling the documentation.

Comment: @Michael Yes. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MagicBooleans is just a class wrapping static bools:

```
/**
 * Global boolean values that control various actions in Program AB
 */
public class MagicBooleans {
    public static boolean trace_mode = true;
    public static boolean enable_external_sets = true;
    public static boolean enable_external_maps = true;
    public static boolean jp_morphological_analysis = false;
    public static boolean fix_excel_csv = true;
}
```

[source on github](https://github.com/lumenrobot/program-ab/blob/master/src/main/java/org/alicebot/ab/MagicBooleans.java)

As they are static, it means you can access them by importing MagicBoolean and other classes will work with the same values if they read for example MagicBooleans.trace_mode.

I'm not sure what the trace_mode is affecting, but you can search in the source code.

The same applies for the MagicStrings - just static strings that you can access using the MagicStrings class. That's all the "Magic".

Comment: @KYL3R Thank You !

Comment: @Sarvesh - If this answered your question, you may accept my answer please.